# jquery load doesn't take all html?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to load a div and all of it content, but it only loads some of the div, why is that? The only thing that it takes in the `#menucontent` div, but not `.dd-content` etc...?

My script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {              
          jQuery(".targetDiv").load("/<xsl:value-of select="@Href" disable-output-escaping="yes"/> #menucontent");
        });
```

The content i want to load, looks like this:

```
<div id="menucontent" class="menu-content" style="display:none;"><div style="" class="dd-content">
<div class="inner">            
        <a class="pidlink" name="7696"></a><p>This is a test</p> 
</div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: If you mean that you want to include a parent element without it's children, that's not possible. You would have to exclude the children manually in jQuery in the callback of the `load()` function.

Comment: Is your `#menucontent` div closed correctly (the example is cut-off)? Can you provide a dump of the entire page you are trying to load as any HTML errors on that page will mess up the load insertion as it needs to a) load the entire page, b) find the target element and c) copy that element into your page's `.targetDiv` element.

Comment: No, I want to include everything in the DIV "menucontent ? Now it only takes the DIV "menucontent", and not the child elements ?